# Neo4j: how to compare elements in different lists so that each row has different elements from the previous rows

Tags: list, graph, neo4j, compare, cypher

I have a query that returns an id and the corresponding list of elements:

```
RETURN i.id, collect(distinct n.name)
```

Is there a way to filter the elements in each list so that each row has not the same elements of the previous ones? For example:

```
i.id | collect(distinct n.name)
------------------------------
1    | [A,B,C,D]
2    | [C,D,E]
3    | [F,G]
4    | [G,H]
```

how can I have:

```
i.id | collect(distinct n.name)
------------------------------
1    | [A,B,C,D]
2    | [E]
3    | [F,G]
4    | [H]
```

The idea is that the second row has not the same elements of the first one, the third row has not the same elements of the second and the first ones and so on

I hope I was able to explain what I’m looking for, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I would post-process this in Python.

Comment: First, you can make this easier by providing the code to create your scenario:

    create (n1:item{id:1,name:'A'})
    create (n2:item{id:1,name:'B'})
    create (n3:item{id:1,name:'C'})
    create (n4:item{id:1,name:'D'})
    create (n5:item{id:2,name:'C'})
    create (n6:item{id:2,name:'D'})
    create (n7:item{id:2,name:'E'})
    create (n8:item{id:3,name:'F'})
    create (n9:item{id:3,name:'G'})
    create (n10:item{id:4,name:'G'})
    create (n11:item{id:4,name:'H'})

Comment: I agree with Adrian, this is perhaps easier with post-processing code.